# Python SSL certificate expired

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

I get this error each time i try to run my program that connects to a temporary mail server to get a verification code to create an account for something. This is the error i get:

**requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.internal.temp-mail.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/email/new (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)')))**

I have tried so many things and none of them work.

Comment: This is almost certainly the Let's Encrypt DST R3 root certificate problem and there are numerous posts here and elsewhere discussing ways to solve it. The basic solution is to upgrade the root certificates on your platform. How to do that is highly dependent on the platform.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk how would I update it on Windows 10?